# How to get parent tables and children tables by retrieve table object properties?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linqpad

I have code below, it used to pull object "Applicant" (table Applicant) properties.

```
void Main()
{
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Applicant).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            prop.Name.Dump();
        }
}
```

The result are:

```
EthnicBackground
Distance
TransplantHospital
Appointments
Employers
Claims
```

EthnicBackground, Distance, TransplantHospital are Applicant's parent tables.

Appointments, Employers, Claims are Applicant's son tables.

Right now the result are parent tables and son tables mixed together.

How to modify the code, separate the output result by parent tables and son tables automatics?

[image]

The Applicant class construction base on database table Applicant like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the PropertyType should be either `typeOf(T)` or `typeOf(EntitySet<T>)` depending on the type of relationship. Hence you can probably distinguish the two by looking to see if the type has any generic arguments, ie something like :

```
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Applicant).GetProperties();

var parents = (from r in props 
               where r.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Count() == 0 
               select r.Name)
               .ToList().Dump();

var children = (from r in props 
                where r.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Count() == 1 
                select r.Name)
               .ToList().Dump();
```

Comment: MANY THANKS SGMOORE! Excellent! It is an amazing solution. :-)

Comment: Hi Sgmoore, just think if return parents/children table name plus table primary key will be very helpfully. Could you please modified the code to get it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you can check PropertyInfo.DeclaringType property. so the code would become (roughly)

```
void Main()
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Applicant).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.DeclaringType == typeof(Applicant)) 
        {
           // this is an Applicant property
           string name = prop.Name;
           // TODO: store wherever you need
        }
        else
        {
           // this is a parent table property
             string name = prop.Name;
           // TODO: store wherever you need
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks James. I just tried your solution. It is not working. The parents and sons tables name still mix together.

Comment: @Matthew How are the classes structured? Is it entering the proper execution path based on the DeclaringType? I am not sure what the method call is doing from your code, but you may need to add something that would distinguish the properties that belong to Applicant vs the parent class. Could you post the class definitions?

Comment: @Matthew I am sorry, I meant the c# class definitions. The Applicant Type inherits from the others correct?